# Certificate error preventing remote desktop to Azure cloud service: 'The certificate does not have a private key.'

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, certificate

I've inherited an cloud service that runs on Azure. I'd like to be able to remote desktop onto that service to make small changes. I want to set this all up via the Azure Portal (i.e. not using Visual Studio or other installed tools).

My understanding is that it's possible to do as there's [an article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop/) written about it.

According to the instructions in that article, setting up remote desktop requires a certificate. The certificate that "came with" the service expired years ago. I am having issues creating a new one that works.

I followed instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-certs-create/) and at other places (which I cannot link due to reputation) to create `.cer` and `.pfx` files with tools like `makecert.exe` and powershell. I uploaded both to the cloud service.

When I try to set up the remote desktop credentials using this certificate, I get the following error:

> Failed to save Remote Desktop settings for deployment slot 'XXXXX'.
>   Error: The operation 'd92d37ce80b93b61bcd4117c5382bb2d' failed: 'The
>   certificate does not have a private key.'. The operation
>   '4322a36b8ebc3fafb7de91cbcbb67973' failed: 'The certificate does not
>   have a private key.'.

I'm guessing I created the `.pfx` and/or `.cer` files wrong? Searching for the error `The certificate does not have a private key` (in the context of Azure or just generally) did not turn up much that would help me.

How can I create a `.pfx` and/or `.cer` file that will have a private key, and will allow me to create remote desktop credentials? My development machine is Windows, so any tools would need to run on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PFX file contains the private key. Actually, the PFX is the filename extension for [PKCS#12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12).

The CER file only contains the public key. You only need to upload the pfx file.

Comment: Thanks. This got me thinking and searching along the right track. In the end I was able to make a *.p12 file using [this site](http://makecert.com/). I deleted the certificate and re-created it, uploading only the p12 file. The 'does not have a private key' error was no more.